# i need to pass a data to the scene and display what i put in the input to the next screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to get the the data I filled in the input to the chat screen but I am getting the key scene name of that screen. How can I fix it?

### Heading

```
 <Router>
    <Scene key="root" style={{paddingTop:Platform.OS==='ios'? 64:54}}> 
     <Scene key="Login" component={Login} hideNavBar={true} hideTabBar={true} />

      <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true} tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}} hideNavBar={true} 
   >
      <Scene key="Home" component={CardList} title="Home" iconName="ios-home" icon={TabIcon}/>
     <Scene key="contacts" component={Contacts} iconName="ios-contacts" icon={TabIcon} /> 
     
      <Scene key='chat' component={Chat} hideTabBar={true} title='Chat'iconName="ios-chatbubbles" icon={TabIcon} />
      <
  
     </Scene>
    </Scene>
  </Router>
```

---

```
 <View style={style.container}>
      <Text> hello{this.props.name}</Text>
 </View>
```

---

**contract**

```js
state={ name:'',}; 
render() { return ( 
<View style={style.container}> 
<Text> Enter your name </Text> 
<TextInput style={style.textInput} onChangeText={(text)=>{ this.setState({ name: text, }); }} value={this.state.name} />
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ Actions.chat({ name: this.state.name, }) }} > 
<Text> Next </Text> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goamn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a matter of name. Name was saving the name of the router. That's why you have to change the parameter name.

You can use this to turn over the data. If you want pass data in `chat`

```js
Actions.chat({passname: this.state.name})
```

You can recover your data in `chat` Screen like this:

```js
     <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        value={this.props.passname}
```

[Example I created](https://snack.expo.io/By00HL97S)

Comment: I need to pass the data in the chat not contacts. look the image I taged :)

Comment: Is your image showing the value you received correctly received? Is the name of status not chat?

Comment: its not showing the value i put in the TextInput but its showing my scene key name.

Comment: @KalidDiriye You can put the value you received in TextInput just like the answer I updated.

Comment: its still the same, i would show u the code more but i cant edit it.  i would like to send u the code.

Comment: state={ name:'',};
  render() {
   
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <Text> Enter your name </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={style.textInput}
          onChangeText={(text)=>{
            this.setState({
              name: text,
            });
          }}
         value={this.state.name}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{
          Actions.chat({
            name: this.state.name,
            
          })
        }}
        >
          <Text>
            Next
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: this is the contact class

Comment: @KalidDiriye I found a solution, and edited the answer. This was a matter of name.